# Gulp settings for bootstrap less files

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to create css file from bootstrap *.less with gulp. Code:

```
gulp.task('bootstrap', function(){
    gulp.src('./bower_components/bootstrap/less/**/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

I get an error message:

> variable @alert-padding is undefined in file /home/www/blog.loc/web/laravel/bower_components/bootstrap/less/alerts.less line no. 10

What I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running all the files through `LESS`, just precompile [bootstrap.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less)-file in the same folder. It ensures that files are imported in correct order.

```
gulp.task('bootstrap', function(){
    gulp.src('./bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```